# Excel - Compute some calculus inside a CDT

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I use a lot of Cross Dynamic Tables in Excel for showing my research datas.

I usually want to show a bar chart with error bar as +/- sem and for this I have to ask my CDT for mean, sd and number of my parameter.

Is it possible to ask a CDT directly for `sd/root(nb)` ?

Comment: Is a CDT the same thing as a pivot table? Are you making pivot charts or regular charts?

Comment: If you're using a pivot table you can always create a calculated field that calculates what you need it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot calculate Standard Error with calculated fields in a Pivot Table. The calculated fields operate on a "row by row" basis so you don't have access to the correct value for "n" or for "stdev".

You can calculate Standard Error from your Pivot table, however, using the "GETPIVOTDATA" spreadsheet function.

Using this data ...

[image]

... I built this simple Pivot Table ...

[image]

... then added this calculation nearby ...

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("StdDev of Data1",A3)/SQRT(GETPIVOTDATA("Count of Data1",A3))
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah that's what I've been doing, but it's tedious. I hoped there was another way...